# No type arguments expected for interface Callback in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, okhttp

```
val apiInterface: ApiInterface =
        ApiClient().getApiClient()!!.create<ApiInterface>(ApiInterface::class.java) ?:
    val call: Call<Contacts?>? = apiInterface.signUp(username, contact, password)
    call.enqueue(object : Callback<Contacts?>() {
        fun onResponse(call: Call<Contacts?>?, response: Response<Contacts?>) {
            val value: String = response.body().getValue()
            val message: String = response.body().getMassage()
            if (value == "success") {
                Toast.makeText(this@SignUpActivity, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                val intent = Intent(this@SignUpActivity, LoginActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            } else if (value == "exists") {
                Toast.makeText(this@SignUpActivity, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this@SignUpActivity, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

        fun onFailure(call: Call<Contacts?>?, t: Throwable) {
            
            Toast.makeText(this@SignUpActivity, "Error! $t", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    })
```

Error : `No type arguments expected for class Call`
I am getting the above error on `<Contacts?>` I am new to Kotlin So, I don't know why I am getting the error.

[image]

I had converted above source code from my Java class.
Here's my [Java code](https://github.com/Istiakshovon/RetrofitCrud/blob/7d7fa47460ac3af121756be30de3ff5e16a46dfc/app/src/main/java/com/istiak/retrofitcrud/SignUpActivity.java#L84).

```
val apiInterface: ApiInterface =
        ApiClient().getApiClient()!!.create<ApiInterface>(ApiInterface::class.java)
    val call: retrofit2.Call<Contacts?>? = apiInterface.signUp(username, contact, password)
    call?.enqueue(object : Callback<Contacts?>() {
        override fun onResponse(call: retrofit2.Call<Contacts?>?, response: Response<Contacts?>) {
            val value: String = response.body()?.getValue()!!
            val message: String = response.body()?.getMassage()!!
            if (value == "success") {
                Toast.makeText(this@SignUpActivity, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                val intent = Intent(this@SignUpActivity, LoginActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            } else if (value == "exists") {
                Toast.makeText(this@SignUpActivity, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this@SignUpActivity, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: retrofit2.Call<Contacts?>?, t: Throwable) {
            
            Toast.makeText(this@SignUpActivity, "Error! $t", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    })
```

[Current error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZ3DF.png)

> Error :`This class does not have a constructor`

Comment: Why you have `?:` at the end of first line ?

Comment: @ADM When I added Java source code it automatically generated... Oh! I actually didn't need that.. I have removed but, my question isn't solve yet...

Comment: try removing constructor call ()

Callback<Contacts?>() to Callback<Contacts?>

And 

val call: retrofit2.Call<Contacts>? = apiIn .............
call?.enqueue(object : Callback<Contacts> {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can U show imports?
Have to be `import retrofit2.Call;` instead of smth else.

Also, need to delete `?:` in the second line

I advise you to read about elvis operator and null safety in Kotlin (it's about how to use this `?`, `?:`, `!!`) [[ link ]](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html)

Comment: `import okhttp3.Callback
import okhttp3.Response`

Comment: But U need `import retrofit2.Callback;` and `import retrofit2.Response;`

Comment: Yes! I have added `import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response`

Comment: I am getting new error by doing as you said...[@Rahul Patil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/751931/rahul-patil) said something on [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66635277/no-type-arguments-expected-for-interface-callback-in-kotlin#comment117795521_66635277) section but, i didn't understand him..

Comment: I understood I had removed `()` from `Callback<Contacts?>()`...problem solved... :)